# Use the variable in code or define string resource in android

Tags: android, string

I've defined a lot of different resources for a different TextView and
A lot of them are the same as below:

```
<string name="total">total</string>
<string name="totalWithColon">total:</string>
<string name="date">date</string>
<string name="dateWithColon">date:</string>
.
.
.
```

Some places are needed ithout :, and in some places needed with colon(:)

but the other way has this:
define one of the eah main word and then define one resorce to colon(:)

```
<string name="total">total</string>
<string name="date">date</string>
.
.
.
<string name="colon">:</string>
.
.
.
```

but this way needed call getString and maybe needed define variable

```
val combinStr1 = getString(R.string.total) + getString(R.string.colon)
val combinStr1 = getString(R.string.date) + getString(R.string.colon)
```

or use directly

```
myveiw.text = getString(R.string.date) + getString(R.string.colon)
```

My question is, which code is better for a better performance?

Comment: How about you measure the performance?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Kotlin,

You could try to make an Extension Function of the Context class such as :

```
fun Context.getStringWithColon(stringResId : String) : 
String = getString(stringResId) + " : "
```

Then in your Code you would simply use it like this :

```
myveiw.text = getStringWithColon(R.string.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to store **everything** in resources, especially in cases like `:`, `-` etc. 
I mean, char symbols that will not by any case be changed or do not need translation.
Unless it's absolutely needed of course. 
In **Kotlin** you can use [string interpolation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#string-interpolation) like this:

```
val combinStr1 = "${getString(R.string.total)}:"
```

it's easy and it's readable.